# How do I set up G1000 GFC700 autopilot for takeoff?

Tags: avionics, autopilot, g1000

I want to be able to engage autopilot right away at a safe altitude, while taking advantage of flight level control at Vy for the climb.

Heading is set for the runway. I’d switch to NAV mode when I was ready to make the turn out.

Altitude is set for cruise altitude.

Does this look like I’m all set to just hit “AP” at a safe altitude, or am I missing anything? Thanks!

[image: G1000]

Comment: Is this for a simulator (what type?) or for an actual aircraft?

Comment: This looks like a proper setup for an autopilot controlled climb up to 5000 feet. One way to know for sure is to see what the Flight Director tells you. Does it seem reasonable and correct?

Comment: Thanks guys. This is a simulator screenshot of course, but I mainly fly a Diamond DA40 in real life. 
Great answer Dean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a proper setup for an autopilot controlled climb up to 5000 feet. One way to know for sure is to see what the Flight Director tells you. Does it seem reasonable and correct?

Also, prior to taking the runway, you should test the autopilot disconnects. Some of the more common ones are:

- Can you overpower the autopilot manually.
- The Control Wheel Steering button
- The Autopilot immediate disconnect button on the yoke.
- The electric trim buttons on the yoke.
- The Take Off Go Around button on the panel.
- The AP button itself
- The Autopilot circuit breaker (this can only be tested during preflight inspection since completely restarting the G1000 will be necessary).